# Java jar reference picking up wrong package with same directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pcf, gosu, guidewire

I have a reference:

`lmg.pm.cl.rules.Activity`

Which is meant to reference an imported `.jar` file.

However the exact same path exists four levels up, but without the Activity class.  This is the incorrect directory, but is the one intelliJ is picking up.  It is causing a `No function descriptor found` error.

When I right click the `.jar` file I need, in intelliJ, and copy the reference, it gives me the exact same above reference.

I've tried Invalidating Cache, tried rebuilding but nothing works.

Is there any way I can be more explicit about the `.jar` reference I need?